# Using a BOOLEAN expression in a #define value

Tags: ios, c-preprocessor, boolean-expression

I usually define my constants like so `#define kIamAconstant` and I have my api endpoint in a constant like this. Now my project requires me to have a toggle that switches this between two different end points for testing. I have a 10s of thousands of lines of code, and rather that go through all the code and change it, I was wondering is there a way I could use a boolean expression within a constant. I have tried this (below) and logging it but it says `Expected expression` when I try and log it.

```
#define kIsLiveEnvironment [IICore isLiveEnvironment]
#define kII_URL  if(kIsLiveEnvironment){@"FirstURL" }else{@"SecondURL"};
```

and then in my view controller I try logging this:

```
 NSLog(@"IS Live environment %@ so use url %@",kIsLiveEnvironment,kII_URL);
```

`IICore isLiveEnvironment` is as follows:

```
+(void)isLiveEnvironment{
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isLive"];
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: `if` is not an expression, it's a statement. You *could* replace the `if` with a ternary conditional expression, but you should really just define a function instead. This is very hackish.

Comment: Instead of a boolean, you may want to use another type, in case you suddenly need to switch between three different end points for testing.

Comment: @OwenHartnett Interesting point, what would you suggest>

Comment: That's really been bugging me too -- it seems like every iOS post over the last couple of weeks are getting thumbed down by someone, with no comments to indicate why.

Comment: #define BUILD_TYPE_1 1 - #define BUILD_TYPE_2 2 - #define REAL_BUILD_TYPE BUILD_TYPE_1 - (replace hyphens with returns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code becomes:

```
NSLog(@"IS Live environment %@ so use url %@",
    [IICore isLiveEnvironment],
    if([IICore isLiveEnvironment]){@"FirstURL" }else{@"SecondURL"};
);
```

which is why you have the error.

Change `kII_URL` to be:

```
#define kII_URL ((kIsLiveEnvironment) ? @"FirstURL" : @"SecondURL")
```

Comment: thanks rmaddy, the mistake was else where. youre answer was perfect in the end.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is

```
#define kII_URL  if(kIsLiveEnvironment){@"FirstURL" }else{@"SecondURL"};
```

Have you try :

```
#define kII_URL  ((kIsLiveEnvironment) ? @"FirstURL" : @"SecondURL")
```

Comment: better parenthesize that macro.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant true :)